# How to connect OK Google voice queries to my app

Tags: android, voice

I want to my app to react to voice queries.
I have setup "Ok Google" properly as described [**here**](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6031948).

It is working fine, but it does not seem to be connected to my app. Instead of opening my app it just performs a regular search!

Comment: Is your issue solved? Do you think my answer is lacking in some way? Is there something else I can do to improve my answer or is there some other reason you haven't accepted it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a searchable `Activity` as described [**here**](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html%23create-sa) then you just need to add these two lines to the `<intent-filter />` tag of your `Activity` in your manifest:

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

After that you will receive the `SEARCH_ACTION` `Intent` in your app which you can handle just like the normal search `Intent`. You can access the query by getting the `String` extra with the key `SearchManager.QUERY` from the `Intent`.

**But** your users need to specify the app name in the verbal query for the `Intent` to reach your app! For example:

> Ok Google, search [query] on [your app name]

---

You can find more information in the blog post [**here**](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2014/10/the-fastest-route-between-voice-search.html).