# Ok Google response in my application?

Tags: android, google-voice-search

Hello all I am working with ok google voice search.

What i want to do is when user say some keyword like "Hello".

[image]

To the home screen ok google.
then ,I want the ok google callback in my application.

For example:
If I say "Hello" to the ok google voice search as shown below.Then I want the "Hello" word to print in my application textView.

Please help if possible,any answer should be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: do you want to integrate your application with ok google?

Comment: Yes i want.but i want response in my app from the google voice search from ok google shown in fig.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689606/android-app-integrated-with-ok-google and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140594/how-to-connect-ok-google-voice-queries-to-my-app

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for your problem is here:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/the-fastest-route-between-voice-search.html
You can access the query by getting the String extra with the key `SearchManager.QUERY`